# understanding std::fmod and std::remainder

Tags: c++, math, stl

Could someone please explain how the functions [std::fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) and [std::remainder](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder) work.  In the case of the `std::fmod`, can someone explain the steps to show how:

```
std::fmod(+5.1, +3.0) = 2.1
```

Same thing goes for `std::remainder` which can produce negative results.

```
std::remainder(+5.1, +3.0) = -0.9
std::remainder(-5.1, +3.0) = 0.9
```

Comment: From your link: "The floating-point remainder of the division operation `x/y` calculated by `fmod(x, y)` is exactly the value `x - n*y`, where `n` is `x/y` with its fractional part truncated. The returned value has the same sign as `x` and is less than `y` in magnitude." What part of this do you find unclear?

Comment: Forgive me for being baffled by your request for a reinterpretation of detailed documentation around a simple mathematical concept, after noticing your profile states you are a developer in the aerospace industry. =P

Comment: Forgiven :), I normally use the integer counterparts mod and div -extremely simple - floating counterparts require a bit more thought, the examples were not worked through in the detailed documentation, that was what was missing and really well explained by P.W.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the reference states for **[std::fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)**:

The floating-point remainder of the division operation `x/y` calculated by this function is exactly the value `x - n*y`, where `n` is `x/y` with its fractional part truncated.

The returned value has the **same sign as** `x` and is less than `y` in magnitude.

So to take the example in the question, when `x = +5.1` and `y = +3.0`, 
`x/y` `(5.1/3.0 = 1.7)` with its fractional part truncated is 1. So `n` is `1`. So the `fmod` will yield `x - 1*y` which is `5.1 - 1 * 3.0` which is `5.1 - 3.0` which is `2.1`.

And the reference states for **[std::remainder](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder)**:
The IEEE floating-point remainder of the division operation `x/y` calculated by this function is exactly the value `x - n*y`, where the value n is the integral value nearest the exact value `x/y`. When `|n-x/y| = ½`, the value `n` is chosen to be even.

So to take the example in the question, when `x = +5.1` and `y = +3.0`
The nearest integral value to `x/y (1.7)` is `2`. So `n` is `2`. So the `remainder` will yield `x - 2y` which is 5.1 - 2 * 3.0 which is `5.1 - 6.0` which is **`-0.9`**.

But when `x = -5.1` and `y = +3.0`
The nearest integral value to `x/y (-1.7)` is `-2`. So `n` is `-2`. So the `remainder` will yield `x - 2y` which is `-5.1 - (-2) * 3.0` which is `-5.1 + 6.0` which is **`+0.9`**

The reference also states that: In contrast to `std::fmod()`, the returned value is **not guaranteed to have the same sign** as `x`.

Answer (score 4):

For those who may have a small difficulty understanding the good example by P.W., here is a slightly less mathematical approach.

`fmod()` function tells you how much remains after dividing your numerator evenly by your denominator.

`remainder()` function tells you how far your numerator is from the next closest number the denominator evenly divides into.

Examples:

`fmod(10,3.5)` = `3`.

`3.5` can fit twice into `10` (`2*3.5 = 7`), leaving a remainder of `3`.

---

`remainder(10,3.5)` = `-0.5`.

`3.5` cannot fit evenly into `10`, but it can fit evenly into `7` (`2*3.5`) and `10.5` (`3*3.5`).

`10.5` is closer to `10` than `7`.

How far away is `10` from `10.5`?

It is `-0.5` away from `10.5`.